# Bloquear tecla CTRL em Todos os Navegadores

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, script

Quero Proteger meu Conteúdo.
Já "Destruí" o Clique com Botão Direito no meu Site,
Mas agora gostaria de Bloquear a tecla CTRL.
Pois ela dá origem á comandos de cópia e cola, e eu não quero usar isso no meu site. Existe algum código para anular a tecla CTRL? Obrigado.

Comment: Esse tipo de coisa não é eficaz e só serve para atrapalhar a vida dos seus usuários.

Comment: Eu sempre ri de sites que bloqueavam o clique do mouse quando eu usava o Opera, era só uma questão de escolher uma opção para não permitir que o site interceptasse o clique do mouse o pronto, tava ele lá funcionando, saudades do finado Opera já que agora ele é uma cópia do Chrome. Mas quanto ao que você quer fazer eu diria para não perder muito tempo com isso, se quer faça apenas o que for mais simples, pois só vai impedir os usuários que não fazem ideia do que estão fazendo, qualquer um com conhecimento básico de como funciona os navegadores vão conseguir burlar isso.

Comment: O Que eu quero fazer é impedir conflitos. Mas coitado do que copiar um conteúdo com direitos autoriais. O Copyright "trituraria" você vivo. Apenas não quero problemas, mas quem passar por essas proteções é intencionalmente, e será merecedor de uma boa punição.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apesar de ser contra esse tipo de técnica, se você adicionar essa regra de CSS no elemento que você quer bloquear deve funcionar

```
p.no-copy{
  -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome Todos / Safari Todos */
  -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox Todos */
  -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;  
}
```

Comment: É, já sabina bloquear a seleção. Estava tentando bloquear a tecla CTRL para impedir os comandos CTRL+A CTRL+C. Obrigado. Você foi um dos únicos que entenderam que eu só quero impedir conflitos. Eu não posso censurar meu conteúdo por causa disso. Obrigado mais uma vez. :)

Answer (score 11):

**Não é possível proteger o texto do seu site.**

Essas medidas são completamente artificiais, são apenas um truque feio com JavaScript. Quem estiver com JavaScript desabilitado poderá fazer o que bem entender. Existem muitas outras formas de obter o texto mesmo se fosse possível bloquear o `Ctrl`, por exemplo: baixar a página via `curl`, exibir o código fonte da página, usar o Inspetor da Web do navegador.

A propósito, proibir usuários de copiar textos seria deselegante e vai contra o princípio aberto e democrático da web. Na internet, as informações devem circular livremente.

---

Imagine que um usuário quer salvar um trecho para si, ou simplesmente pesquisar a definição de uma palavra num dicionário online. Se você bloqueia a cópia, apenas prejudica esse usuário, o leigo, que não planeja malícias. O usuário experiente, que deseja *roubar* o texto do seu site, usaria as técnicas que eu comentei.

Comment: Não, Não acho isso. São Direitos autoriais, Copyright.

Comment: Copyright é um direito que deve ser assegurado pela lei, através do procedimento jurídico de cada país. Não cabe a tecnologia **impedir** esse tipo de coisa. Se você realmente acha que os direitos de cópia deveriam ser assegurados na internet, deveria manter sua preciosa propriedade intelectual afastada da web: [http://www.go-gulf.com/blog/online-piracy/] (20% de toda a banda mundial é usada para pirataria). A internet não é um lugar propício para _direitos autorais_, mesmo que você considere errado :)

Comment: Moço, A Internet não é obrigada á proteger meu conteúdo. Mas todos os sites que você costumar dar cliques no Google tem direitos autoriais. O Que eu quero apenas é evitar que alguém pegue o meu conteúdo, afinal, eu vou compartilhá-lo, mas ele é meu. Coitado do que se mete com direitos autoriais.

Comment: @HugoMarcelo Quantos 5 minutos você acha que vai demorar até alguém conseguir burlar isso e publicar em algum outro lugar só para trollar exatamente pelo motivo de o conteúdo ser supostamente protegido?

Comment: @HugoMarcelo o que pretende fazer é seguramente 100% insano....... Se algum engraçadinho copiar o seu tao precioso conteúdo, basta você entrar na justiça com uma ação judicial, agora, a ideia de IMPEDIR, é impossível.... o máximo seria DIFICULTAR......

Comment: http://ultimosegundo.ig.com.br/cultura/para+especialistas+internet+redefine+direito+autoral+e+dominio+publico/n1597128623872.html

Comment: @HugoMarcelo Isso que você quer é só para dificultar, pois impedir você não conseguira. Para eu pegar o conteúdo do seu site no firefox por exemplo, eu digitaria na URL `view-source:http://www.seu-site.com.br` e já era. Pego o código fonte com o texto/conteúdo que preciso. Não quero desencorajar você, mas isso só irá impedir talvez usuários muito leigos na questão web. Usuários mais experientes já pegaram seu conteúdo em 5 minutos.

Comment: @HugoMarcelo O que você pode fazer TALVEZ para **dificultar** mais ainda é minificar o código, deixar tudo em uma linha só.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode evitar que "copiem" do seu site usando os eventos [oncopy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/oncopy) e [oncut](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/oncut):

```
<body oncopy="return false" oncut="return false">
```

Tenha em mente que isso fará com que seja impossível copiar e colar também de elementos `input[type=text]` e `textarea`.

Porém, na minha opinião, é realmente muito chato quando algum site faz isso, além de ser fácil passar por cima dessas restrições.

Comment: Fácil, Mas Ilegal. A Razão de eu fazer isso é evitar que pessoas tenham problemas de plágio comigo, eu não gosto nem um pouco de contendas. Mas se necessário, e a pessoa passar por cima do Copyright, esse código pelo menos vai ajudar a evitar. Entendeu? :)

Answer (score 0):

Pode utilizar `oncopy="return false"` ou `oncut="return false"` mas nem todos navegadores suportam. Uma forma alternativa que funciona em todos seria:

```
window.onkeydown = function() {
   var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode || e.which;
   if(key==17){ alert('Proibida copia deste site.'); return false; }
}
```

Utiliza-se o evento `window.onkeydown` para detectar a tecla que foi pressionada, a qual recebe os métodos identificadores `keyCode`, `charCode` em `event` e `which`. Ambos parâmetros de retorno de evento, mas diferentes em MSIE, Webkit e Genko. O `alert` não permite a execução da próxima tecla, e o `return` cancela a execução.

Comment: Amigo, muitooo obrigado!!! Funcionou perfeitamente no chrome, internet explorer, e opera....

porém no firefox passa direto, tem alguma dica?